# Wrong PHP version after installation (OSX)

Tags: php, macos, apache

I am running OSX El Capitan which comes (if I am not wrong) with PHP 5.5.

So I updated my PHP version using this Terminal command:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

And from the [docs](http://php-osx.liip.ch/) :

> php-osx doesn't overwrite the php binaries installed by Apple, but
>   installs everything in /usr/local/php5. The new php binary is
>   therefore in /usr/local/php5/bin/php.
>
> You can also adjust your PATH do include that directory, eg. write
>   into your ~/.profile file the following

So I did what have been suggested, but still, my php version (shown by php -v) is 5.5 rather than 5.6.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Did you restart your terminal? What's the output of echo $PATH?

Comment: @nanodanger Seems that everything worked after I have restarted the terminal. Or at least I guess that was the fix. Also I've edited ~/.bash_profile , not ~/.profile file. You can write your answer if you like because some of these helped.

Comment: Ok! I've added some extra info, so that way you don't even have to restart the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` you either have to restart your terminal or do `source ~/.profile` so the changes take effect immediately.

Comment: The weird thing is that php -v in terminal shows PHP 5.6.21 (cli) built built: May 24 2016 23:20:56. But phpinfo(); shows PHP Version 5.5.31 ? Any idea what is going on ?

Comment: I think you have to tell apache to use the new php version. You can check it in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf searching for php5_module and modifying the path to the new version.

Comment: So, right now I have : LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so ... What actually do you mean by modifying the path ?

Comment: You installed php to  /usr/local/php5/, so you should have /usr/local/php5/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Comment: Actually I did that, but I got this error (by running apachectl configtest) : *Syntax error on line 170 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/php5/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/php5/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, 10): image not found*

Comment: Actually it should be : LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so So it working now. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: I've installed the new php version with homebrew and it has the libexec directory. Seems like this installation uses a different structure. Anyways, I'm glad you got it working.